# Android - Make AlertDIalog buttons a uniform size

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an alert dialog with a positive and negative button added programatically. In the dialog layout there are also two buttons, above the AlertDialog's native buttons.

[image: dialog]

When these two are right next to each other, I realized that in this dialog, the native positive/negative/neutral buttons are not equally weighted. The content of their text determines their horizontal weight, rather than each taking up 50% (or 33% if 3 buttons) of the dialog. So in my case, where the negative button's text is longer than that positive  button's text, we get something that looks like the image I posted above.

I can't find a way to fix this, does anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

XML as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/rcd_msg"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_margin="8dp"
              android:text="@string/rating_dialog_text"
              android:textSize="14dp"
              android:textColor="@android:color/white"
              android:gravity="center"/>

    <RatingBar android:id="@+id/rcd_rating_bar"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@id/rcd_msg"
               android:layout_margin="8dp"
               android:paddingBottom="10dp"
               android:numStars="5"
               android:rating="0"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/rcd_rating_bar">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rcd_image"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="@color/selectable_transparent"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/rcd_image_text"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                          android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                          android:gravity="center"
                          android:text="@string/add_image"
                          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                          android:textSize="16sp"
                          android:clickable="true"/>

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/rcd_image_img"
                           android:layout_height="32dp"
                           android:layout_width="32dp"
                           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                           android:layout_margin="8dp"
                           android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rcd_image_text"
                           android:scaleType="centerInside"
                           android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rcd_comment"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="@color/selectable_transparent"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/rcd_comment_text"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                          android:paddingRight="6dp"
                          android:gravity="center"
                          android:text="@string/add_comment"
                          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                          android:textSize="16sp"
                          android:clickable="true"/>

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/rcd_comment_img"
                           android:layout_height="32dp"
                           android:layout_width="32dp"
                           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                           android:layout_margin="4dp"
                           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rcd_comment_text"
                           android:scaleType="centerInside"
                           android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_comment"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="1dp"
                      android:layout_height="38dp"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_margin="10dp"
                      android:background="@color/transparent_white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: would you mind sharing your layout xml?

Comment: sure, but the xml isn't what causes the buttons to be unevenly weighted, that's from the AlertDialog class

Comment: you could try adding spaces before, after, or before and after the submit button title like `" Submit"` or `" Submit "`. This is a little sloppy but it might help you adjust the weight.

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't realize you add them programmatically

Comment: @John I thought about that, but in the past when I've used getString(R.string.whatever) to combine words/sentences together I remember that it seems to call trim() on the string before publishing it, it's worth a try though. But even if I can get it looking good on my test device here, I don't know if that solution will be applicable to all screen sizes. I'll give it a try and fill you in.

Comment: @John yea, as I thought adding spaces doesn't change anything, I think trim() is called before the string is displayed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out a solution... don't know why I didn't think of it before.

I do the following:

```
mRateConcertDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface d) {
        Button posButton = mRateConcertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        Button negButton = mRateConcertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

        LayoutParams posParams = (LayoutParams) posButton.getLayoutParams();
        posParams.weight = 1;
        posParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        LayoutParams negParams = (LayoutParams) negButton.getLayoutParams();
        negParams.weight = 1;
        negParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        posButton.setLayoutParams(posParams);
        negButton.setLayoutParams(negParams);
    }
});
```

Basically, you have to manipulate the size of the buttons AFTER the dialog is shown. So create an onShowListener and you can just set weights and widths that way. Thanks for the comments, I hope this can help someone in the future.