# how to customize alertdialog so that buttons fit in the alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am using the following pieces of codes to create alertdialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light));
    View pickerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.picker_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(pickerView);
    builder.setMessage("AlertDialog").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }).setNeutralButton("Neutral", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "neutralize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("number picker");
    alert.show();
```

the problem is when i use this code to create the dialog, those three buttons are not evenly placed, like this:

[image]

actually what i want to get is something like this:

[image]

in which those two buttons are equally placed

i know this is the problem with alertdialog theme. but i tried endless times i cant change anything.

Can anybody tell me what to do with theme to get a alertdialog like second one?

the layout file for picker_dialog is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="input"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I follow the suggestion at [Android - Make AlertDIalog buttons a uniform size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982357/android-make-alertdialog-buttons-a-uniform-size). the code is as follow:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
    View pickerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.picker_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(pickerView);
    builder.setMessage("AlertDialog").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Verify", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Neutral", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("number picker");
    alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button posButton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button negButton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            Button neuButton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams posParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) posButton.getLayoutParams();
            posParams.weight = 1;
            posParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            posParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams negParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) negButton.getLayoutParams();
            negParams.weight = 1;
            negParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            posParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams neuParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) neuButton.getLayoutParams();
            neuParams.weight = 1;
            neuParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            neuParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;


            posButton.setLayoutParams(posParams);
            negButton.setLayoutParams(negParams);
            neuButton.setLayoutParams(neuParams);
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

the above is complete codes after following the suggestion at the link above. and i only got this:[image]

seems the positive button has pushed to the right corner and disappeared.

can someone solve this?

according to Kushan's suggestion, I take the layout settings codes out of dialog onshow listener and the complete code is as follow:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog));
    View pickerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.picker_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(pickerView);
    builder.setMessage("AlertDialog").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Positive", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Negative", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Neutral", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Neutral", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("number picker");
    alert.show();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams;
    Button buttonPositive = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    buttonParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) buttonPositive.getLayoutParams();
    buttonParams.weight = 1;
    buttonParams.width = buttonParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    Button buttonNegative = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    buttonParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) buttonNegative.getLayoutParams();
    buttonParams.weight = 1;
    buttonParams.width = buttonParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    Button buttonNeutral = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
    buttonParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) buttonNeutral.getLayoutParams();
    buttonParams.weight = 1;
    buttonParams.width = buttonParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

I got the same result as the above

[image]

Comment: That's how it's shown in Material design theme. https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#

Comment: Use DialogFragment to create your own custom Dialog

Comment: but its not what i want. what i want to get is what the second photo looks like

Comment: but you also have to include alertDialog,Builder in the onCreateDIalog function. which would be the same result. i know the problem is with the theme of alertdialog. but i dont know how to adjust the theme

Comment: Add your custom dialog layout XML file here

Comment: i didn't do any layout. those three button is positive, negative and neutral button that can be automatically added to alertdialog programmatically@Kushan

Comment: If you want to customize button positions, you need this xml layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try You alert dialog code like below:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light));
View pickerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.picker_dialog, null);
builder.setView(pickerView);
builder.setMessage("AlertDialog").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}).setNeutralButton("Neutral", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "neutralize", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2f);
        negativeButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        positiveButton.setLayoutParams(params);

        negativeButton.invalidate();
        positiveButton.invalidate();
    }
});
alert.setTitle("number picker");
alert.show();
```

Comment: can you please tell me how things happen when your codes run?@pRaNaY

Comment: `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` with weight value `2f`. when apply param to both button(child's) its parent behave as `LinerarLayout` with weight value 2. and both button fit in layout.

Comment: what if I only have two buttons. I used your method when I set only positive and negative buttons, these two buttons are not evenly placed.

Comment: how do you deal with the situation where there are only positive and negative buttons.@pRaNaY

Comment: as per button size `weight` value change

Comment: can you pls tell me what's the code when i set only positive and negative button and i want these two buttons evenly fit in layout?

Answer (score 0):

change theme of dialog.

it will solve your issue.

use `Holo.Dialog` from your xml layout and check it from preview.

if you want button like that than you have to use `weightSum`.

hope this is helpfull.

Comment: tell me if there is issue ?@Jensen

Comment: i want the buttons are placed like the second photo.

Comment: I run my code only to get three buttons placed like the first photo.

Comment: Actually how it is looks like now?

Comment: the first screenshot.

Comment: and i want to achieve what the second photo looks like, which is that the buttons are equally distributed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982357/android-make-alertdialog-buttons-a-uniform-size

Comment: if you want your button like that than you need to follow link of @FebiMFelix

Comment: I tried the method it mentions. seems not function properly@FebiMFelix

Comment: post your picker_dialog.xml @Jensen

Comment: I already did and shows the results after i follow the suggestion from the link he offers@AmitVaghela

Answer (score 0):

hi you can mack a custom dialog  withe your own custom lay out 
her is a sample  code

```
 private void CustomAlert ()
{

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.CustomViewName );
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.Upload_File_now);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

        final EditText description_editTextField = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
        final EditText locationEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.placeEditText);

        Button cancel_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        Button send_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
        send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String location = locationEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                String description = description_editTextField.getText().toString().trim();
                boolean isUrgent = ((CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxUrgent)).isChecked();

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

i hope this helps you with your project

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use CustomDialog like this

In XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Dismiss" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Avtivity

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        //setting custom layout to dialog
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cusotm_dialog_layout);
        dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

        //adding text dynamically
        TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        txt.setText("Put your dialog text here.");

        ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));

        //adding button click event
        Button dismissButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
        dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: actually i dont want to do any xml layout. i know its problem with theme of alertdialog. I just dont how to change theme to make it look like the buttons in second photos.@Narendra Motwani